# Order BY 2 fields in FQL

Tags: facebook, api, sorting, facebook-fql

I'm trying to sort friends by 2 criterias those who use my app first and has the most number mutual friends with me. Is there any way to sort by 2 fields in FQL?

I've found work around using mutual_friend_count * is_app_user as a sorting criteria, but it works only for app_user = 1 and doesn't perform sorting for those who is 0.

The original query is:

```
SELECT uid, name, is_app_user, mutual_friend_count  
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2    FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND uid != me() ORDER BY (mutual_friend_count * is_app_user) DESC LIMIT 333
```

[Execute](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=%20%20%20%20SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20is_app_user%2C%20mutual_friend_count%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20FROM%20user%20%0A%20%20%20%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%28SELECT%20uid2%20%20%20%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%20AND%20uid%20!%3D%20me%28%29%20ORDER%20BY%20%28mutual_friend_count%20%2a%20is_app_user%29%20DESC%20LIMIT%20333) in graph API/FQL explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've found work around using mutual_friend_count * is_app_user as a sorting criteria, but it works only for app_user = 1 and doesn't perform sorting for those who is 0.

Of course it doesn’t, because f.e. 66 * 0 gives the same sorting value as 15 * 0 does.

But assuming no one has a mutual friend count greater than 99999, you could sort by `is_app_user * 99999 + mutual_friends_count`.

This will give app users a “base value” of 99999, and get the number of mutual friends added. For non-app-users, the base value will still be 0, and get the number of mutual friends added as well.

So app users will have a much higher sort value than non-app-users, and will thereby get ranked first – with the added mutual_friends_count taken into account. Non-app-users will still get ranked by their mutual_friends_count, but only after the app users, because they have a much lower sort value.

The only thing that can be a little tricky, is getting the + sign into the query – it has to be URL-encoded as %2B when passing it to the Graph API Explorer via URL, but it does not *show* it as part of the query afterwards. But from a look at the result, it seems to be using it in making the query nevertheless:

[See example query here.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20is_app_user%2C%20mutual_friend_count%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%20AND%20uid%20%21%3D%20me%28%29%20ORDER%20BY%20%28mutual_friend_count%20%2B%20is_app_user%20%2A%2099999%29%20DESC%20LIMIT%20333)